# How to Connect to Coinbase wallet extension with coinbase wallet SDK?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, coinbase-api, decentralized-applications

I am trying to connect my coinbase wallet extension from my react app. I have followed the official docs that guide how to do it using the @coinbase/wallet-sdk, but I cannot connect to the wallet nor I am able to open the extension's popup in chrome. 
Here is the function that I am using,

```js
const connectToCoinBase = async () => {
    const APP_NAME = "Lottery";
    const APP_LOGO_URL = "";
    const DEFAULT_ETH_JSONRPC_URL =
      "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/my-api-key";
    const DEFAULT_CHAIN_ID = 4;

    const coinbaseWallet = new CoinbaseWalletSDK({
      appName: APP_NAME,
      appLogoUrl: APP_LOGO_URL,
      darkMode: false,
    });
    

    const ethereum = coinbaseWallet.makeWeb3Provider(
      DEFAULT_ETH_JSONRPC_URL,
      DEFAULT_CHAIN_ID
    );
  ]

    const account = ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" }); //gives undefined
   
    const web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
  };
```

How to popup for the extension will open? How to get the address from the wallet after the connection is accepted?

Answer (score 0):

It's not required to use the coinbase SDK to connect.
Try connecting using ethereum api. It connects to Coinbase Wallet and MetaMask.

```
  try {
      const { ethereum } = window as any
      if (ethereum) {
        const web3js = new Web3(ethereum)
        await ethereum.enable
        const accounts = await web3js.eth.getAccounts();
      }else {
         console.log('Wallet is not installed!');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Failed connecting to wallet: ', err)
    }
```

Also For Supporting the Mobile and Desktop Wallets, you should use [walletconnect][1]
[1]: https://walletconnect.com/